# Executing a statistical test across multiple subsets using purrr map

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I'm trying to use purr `map` functionality to create a number of sub-groups from a dataframe so that I can run a statistical test on each sub-group. So using `mtcars` as a sample data set, I can determine the set of unique carb values from:

```
mtcars %>% {unique(.$carb)}
```

gives `[1] 4 1 2 3 6 8`

Similarly, the set of unique gear values:

```
mtcars %>% {unique(.$gear)}
```

gives `[1] 4 3 5`

I'd like to iterate through the unique combinations of `carb` and `gear` and use this as a way to subset values within `mtcars`, so that I can perform a statistical test on each subset (as indexed by `gear` and `carb`). So the test would be:

```
data_subset %>% kruskal.test(.$mpg, .$am, data = .)
```

I've tried to do this using `map` from purrr. Something along the lines of:

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
  {unique(.$carb)} %>%
  map2(mtcars, ~filter(.y, am == .x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most combinations of carb/gear in `mtcars`, there is only one value of `am`. From my limited understanding of the help & error messages, you need multiple groups (`am` in you example) to run the test.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Step 1 - limit to testable data
count(mtcars, carb, gear, am) %>%
  count(carb, gear) %>% # Count am possibilities w/in each carb/gear group
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  left_join(mtcars) -> mtcars_mult_am 

# Step 2 - nest, map each group to test, unnest
mtcars_mult_am %>%
  nest(data = -c(carb, gear)) %>%
  mutate(kruskal_raw = map(data, ~ kruskal.test(.x$mpg, .x$am)),
         kruskal = map(kruskal_raw, broom::tidy)) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(kruskal)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
   carb  gear kruskal_raw statistic p.value parameter method                      
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>          <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                       
1     2     4 <S3: htest>      0      1             1 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
2     4     4 <S3: htest>      2.67   0.102         1 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```

Comment: This is great, and apologies, I hadn't appreciated that the `am` variable has insufficient data - I was looking for a variable that would partition the data into two groups.